# pywin32 is in an unsupported or invalid wheel

Tags: python, pywin32, python-wheel

I am trying to install win32con/pywin32 and it gives me the error pywin32 is in an unsupported or invalid wheel and help would be nice

Comment: Are you trying to install it on Windows?  What command are you using to install it?

Answer (score 1):

it's `pip install pypiwin32` but incase that doesn't work remember that pywin32 302 (not pypiwin32, which looks like a mistake from 2018) was uploaded 20 hours ago, and states in the change log:

> Support for Python 10, dropped support for Python 3.5 (3.5 security support ended 13 Sep 2020)

Demo (using PyLauncher to update my 3.10 install):

```
C:\>py -3.10 -m pip install pywin32
Collecting pywin32
  Downloading pywin32-302-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (9.2 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 9.2 MB 6.8 MB/s
Installing collected packages: pywin32
Successfully installed pywin32-302
```