# pywin32 is in an unsupported or invalid wheel/robotframework

Tags: robotframework, pywin32, robotframework-ide

When I tried to install robotframework-ride, I met below error:"pywin32 is in an unsupported or invalid wheel"
I am using pip install robotframework-ride.
Does any one know what's the issue? thanks.

Notes: I am using the virtual environment , python 3.6

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pywin32 is in an unsupported or invalid wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69532906/pywin32-is-in-an-unsupported-or-invalid-wheel)

Comment: Use `python -3.10 -m pip install pywin32`

Comment: *  `py -3.10 -m pip install pywin32`

Comment: Hi JFan, 
I got below issue:
Unknown option: -3
usage:Python [option]...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, RIDE was created long before Virtual environments exist, so it is not the recommended process.

After the virtual env activation you should be sure to use its Python. So for example:

```
path_to_virtual_env\bin\python -m pip install wxPython
path_to_virtual_env\bin\python -m pip install --pre robotframework-ride
```

This may help to troubleshoot your installation.