# Trouble installing packages in Python - ... is in an unsupported or invalid wheel

Tags: python, pip

Hi I am trying to install win10toast and I get this message:

[image]

I had this error when I tried to download pywin32 previously, but why is this error popping up whenever I try to install any other package? I used to be able to install packages fine before with the same command

Comment: Does this resolve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69532906/pywin32-is-in-an-unsupported-or-invalid-wheel

Comment: I tried this, also using 3.8 but I get the same error

Comment: For search purposes and to improve your results, please paste the plain text of your output into a code formatted block. Posting images of text is less useful than plain text for several reasons, screen readers being one, search is another, etc. You may also want to reword your title for better answers: "pywin32 is an unsupported or invalid wheel". Keep in mind that we already know you are having trouble since you are posting a question in SO. :)

Answer (score 1):

`pywin32` is listed as a requirement for the package `win10toast` ([link](https://pypi.org/project/win10toast/)). So, when you are installing `win10toast`, pip also tries to install `pywin32` which gives you an error.

From the looks of it, you are using a python 3.6 and a 32-bit system, both of which are supported by the latest release (pywin32 302). To resolve the pywin32 error, you could try the following.

- Option 1: Considering there are multiple installs and `python3` is mapped to python 3.6 installation. (You can check that using `python --version`)

  - Install using `python -m pip install pypiwin32`
  - If you had a prior successful install on pypiwin32, you could actually try to use: `python Scripts/pywin32_postinstall.py -install`
- Option 2: Download the binary files and install - https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases/tag/b302

  - Download the appropriate exe and install
- Option 3: Download the source files and build:

  - Download the zip file from: https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases/tag/b302
  - Unzip the file
  - Use the command `python setup.py install`

---

**Update:**

I was looking around the `pywin32` github repo and found that the same issue is encountered by [others](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues/1771) too. While an official update is not rolled out, you can try the solution there:

1. you need to download the wheel found [here](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/actions/runs/1343774075)
2. Install the whl manually using the command: `python -m pip install C:/some-dir/pywin32-302.1-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl`

Comment: Thank you. I struggled with getting rid of the pywin32 error although I did extensive research. I also tried with pypiwin32

Comment: You could try and build from the source if most of the solutions do now work for you. I will update my answer with the same

Comment: @cinelli88 I have updated my answer with some solutions that could help with the installation

Comment: Thank you. When I try option 1, the command looks like it is ignored, as if I just typed Ctrl+c. For option2, I could not download the exe as my company does not allow it. For option 3, I get error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

Comment: @cinelli88 can you tell me what output you get when you run "python --version"

Comment: I get Python 3.6.5

Comment: @cinelli88 I tried to look into the issue a bit more and found out some more details that I have updated my answer with.

Comment: Thank you very much. I clicked on the link to download the .whl, but I could not find the pywin32-302.1-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl

Comment: @cinelli88 Download the 'wheels' file that is present over there. Once you unzip it, you will be able to find the pywin32-302.1-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl